Union between an array and a struct of arrays. Can memory layout be tested at comptime?
While experimenting with the C language, I realized that I could "name" my matrix dimensions using a union.
typedef union {
    float a[2][10];
    struct {
        float a_0[10];
        float a_1[10];
    };
} Matrix_t;

void main(void) {
    Matrix_t foo = {.a[1][5] = 42.0f};

    assert(42.0f == foo.a_1[5]); // it works !
}

I know that struct and union can be padded depending on the architecture, but I'm unsure of their interaction when used together with arrays.
Is there a way to guarantee at compile-time that the memory layout will be valid? (I'm open to using gcc/clang extension if need be)
Maybe something like this?
_Static_assert(sizeof((Matrix_t){0})==sizeof(float[2][10]));


I'm not sure what you mean by "guarantee at compile-time that the memory layout will be valid"  but you can for sure use _Static_assert to assert on the size at compile time. I'm also not sure why you use sizeof((Matrix_t){0}) instead of just sizeof(Matrix_t) or sizeof foo.

Hi @TedLyngmo, thanks for your answer. Let's say that for speed, the compiler decides to pad float a_0[10]; suddenly the a_1[0] won't be aligned with a[1][0] anymore; breaking the code.

I see. Yes, in that case the current static assertion should do the trick. Sidenote: Not all C compilers will accept void main(void). If you want portability, use int main(void)

You should know that such usage of unions is incompatible with C++.

Thanks @n.m.couldbeanAI (great name btw). Yeah, I'm aware that union type-punning is undefined in C++.
But you're completely right; this is something to consider.

The offsetof macro can be used:
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h> // for offsetof

typedef union {
    float a[2][10];
    struct {
        float a_0[10];
        float a_1[10];
    };
} Matrix_t;

_Static_assert(offsetof( Matrix_t, a[1][5] ) == offsetof( Matrix_t, a_1[5] ));

int main()
{
}


interesting approach! Especially that offsetof becomes portable in c23.
